# Infopath 2010 setting focus on a field in .NET Code?

Tags: .net, infopath, infopath2010

I'm building a desktop (thick) Infopath 2010 form with code-behinds that need to set form focus on certain fields so that they are on the field in question for easier entry.  Is there a way to do this in .NET?  Offhand I can't seem to find a way.

Comment: What do you mean "set form focus on occasion"? You want to set the focus on a field, so it is selected?

Comment: moontear, added some clarity, but yes exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the SelectText method of the View class

Link for script
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb251012(v=office.12).aspx

Link for managed code
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.infopath.view.selecttext.aspx